# using Array map method in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

How do I render a JSON data dynamically into a component using something like an array.map method with Typescript. for example. I get an error from the code below.

```
const PricingSection: FC<IProps> = ({ icon, title, price, user, observations,
projects, interviews, buttonType }) => 

const mapped = map(datas => (

        <ul style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            {datas.icon}
        </ul>
    )
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I've tried using something like this:

import data from './data.json' 

const mapped = data.map(datas => {
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>

<li></li>
</ul>

it's not working

Comment: [Edit] the question to give a [mre].

Comment: *What* error do you get?

Comment: (parameter) datas: any
Parameter 'datas' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

Comment: Again, **put the info in the question**. So did you research that error message? What *is* `map`, does it take any generic types etc.? Or have you tried adding an explicit type to the arrow function's parameter list?

Answer (score 0):

You're seemingly not far off... Assuming it's the 'observations' prop that is the array you're wanting to traverse:

```
const mapped = observations.map(datas => (

        <ul style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            {datas.icon}
        </ul>
    )
```

In response to the comment chain where you call out `(parameter) datas: any Parameter 'datas' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)` , that is more of a linter typing callout than an error... 
It is saying that you are implicitly having the type

```
(datas: any =>
```

You can resolve it by explicitly putting a type on the datas object like this:

```
(datas: DataObject =>
```